# How to load a non-routable component in Blazer

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on a project that uses Blazer for the front-end and Cosmos DB in the back-end. I am looping through a list of items and have a button/ anchor tag that OnClick receives a parameter. Currently, I am using the query string parameters to redirect the user from one page to another page. However, I do not want to use query string. I want to make the component non-routable and load it on a button click. Is there a way to pass the parameter on button click and load a non-routable component?
Thank you very much for your explanation, I am using .net 5. Here I am going to write a sample code, so you could help.
My project uses Azure Cosmos DB and Blazor Server.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    ///////////////////////////
    MoviesListComponent.razor
    ////////////////////////
    @page "/movies"
    foreach(movie in ListOfMovies){
    <div> movie.ReleaseeDate</div>
    <div> movie.Country</div>
    <div> movie.Title</div>
    <button type="button" @onClick="()=>LoadAnotherComponent(movie.title)"> on button click redirect to(or load) a non-routable compnent and send movie.title as parameter for example MovieTitleAnalysis component</button>  
    }
    @code{
    public List<Movie> ListOfMovies {get;set;}
    }
     
    on button click inside MoviesListComponent load 
    MovieTitleAnalysis.razor and pass the parameter. Dispose MovieListComponent
     
     
     
    ///////////////////////
    MovieTitleAnalysis.razor is a non routable component
    //////////////////
    <div>welcome to movie Title analysis</div>
     
    @code{
     [paramter]
     public string movieTitle {get;set;}
     
     void PreformSomeOpration(){}
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Nested Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#nested-components).

Answer (score 0):

As this is conceptual - you have provided no code context - this should provide a good starting point and demo the basic concept.  Comment on how well/poorly it fits!

I've pointed to the "routed" components but it will work with any component.

`DynamicPage.razor`

```
@if (ComponentType != null)
{
    <DynamicComponent Parameters=this.Parameters Type=this.ComponentType />
}
else
{
    @this.ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IDictionary<string, object>? Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

And `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
@*Example Menu*@
<div class="p-2 m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => this.ChangePage(null)">Change to Index</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => this.ChangePage(typeof(Counter))">Change to Counter</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="() => this.ChangePage(typeof(FetchData))">Change to FetchData</button>
</div>

<DynamicPage ComponentType=this.page>
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div>Hello World from Blazor</div>

</DynamicPage>

@code {
    private Type? page = null;

    private void ChangePage(Type? newPage)
        => this.page = newPage;
}
```